# Sum of two random variable X and -X

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables such that $X$ and $-Y$ have the same distribution. Prove that $P(X+Y<-t)=P(X+Y>t)$. I know how to prove this when $X$ and $Y$ are independent but how do I prove this for when they are dependent?

Comment: Hint: Can you show that $X+Y$ has the same distribution as $-(X+Y)= (-X)+(-Y)$?

Comment: I can show that but I'm not sure how that can help.

Comment: @user2770287 Can you? Then, how? (And if you can, your question is solved.)

Answer (score 0):

If $X\sim -Y$ then $X+Y \sim -Y-X$.   It follows that $\mathsf P(X+Y < - t) = \mathsf P(-Y-X < - t)$.

$$\therefore \mathsf P(X+Y< -t) = \mathsf P(X+Y> t)$$

Basically, if $X$ and $-Y$ are distributed identically then the sum $X+Y$ is distributed symmetrically about $0$.

Comment: When $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, I'm having trouble seeing why $X+Y \sim -Y-X$?

Comment: Okay, @user2770287.  Let there be two more RV, $W$ and $Z$ such that $W\sim Y$ and $Z\sim X$. Which means $W\sim -X$ and $Z\sim -Y$.  Then can you see that $X+Y \sim Z+W, Z+W \sim -Y-X$ and thus $X+Y\sim -Y-X$?  Because "has the same distribution as" ($\sim$) is an equivalence relation.

Comment: So in general, if $A$ and $B$ have the same distribution and $C$ and $D$ have the same distribution then $A+C$ and $B+D$ have the same distribution?

Comment: Surely the argument in your (Graham) last comment is wrong. One cannot choose any random variables W and Z with the prescribed distributions and hope that Z+W is related to X+Y. And since the whole solution relies on this argument, this is annoying...

Comment: Graham: Why do you fail to react to some precise serious mathematical questions about your answers? Forced to downvote, if only to signal that the solution is incomplete.